# Why does dcfldd always fail on cd-roms that also contain music?

Tags: dd, cd-drive, cd-image, cd-ripping

Ive been working on digitizing my entire library of physical discs, using dcfldd to make disc image copies of every cd-rom & dvd Ive ever owned so I can take them off to the thrift store and save on space.

About 80% of discs copy with no complaints, but Ive noticed one category of cd-rom is always failing with a i/o error, namely any type of older cd-rom disc (usually from games) that has a main partition with the game files, and then a second partition set up like an audio cd (so when the cd-rom is inserted into my disc drive two discs show up as mountable in my file manager). AFAIK this was a big feature way back in the 90s because it made it possible to take a game cd-rom and pop it into your walkman or whatever to play the games soundtrack like a regular music cd.

Anyways, as far as I can tell, none of the discs in question are actually corrupted, its just this dual cd-rom and music cd setup thats giving dcfldd fits. if I run

sudo dcfldd bs=4M if=/dev/cdromdevice of=./makeMeADiscImage.iso

it fails fairly early with an IO error, however if I run

sudo dd bs=4M if=/dev/cdromdevice of=./makeMeADiscImage.iso

instead, DD still hits a I/O error, but manages to make a full copy of the game files partition (so the game can be installed as usual, but music is absent since the application cant find the music on the virtual copy version of the disc like it could on the original).

Does anyone know why dcfldd and dd have these issues, and is there any way of working around this so I make a proper copy of my old games and get rid of the physical discs?